# Ubuntu alongside Windows vista

Tags: 16.04, windows-vista

[I am stuck here]

[image]

I want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows Vista but all tutorials are too old, anyone knows what I have to do to keep all my files and keep Linux in the 20gb partition.

Can someone tells me how to do it or is there a new tutorial that you would suggest.

thanks

Comment: Is Vista new? It EoL for many years.

Comment: 20GBs is okay, but think it is a bit on the small side unless you don't download much.  16.04 will become unsupported next year, like vista already is.  18.04 or the new 20.04 will give 3 and 5 years of support.  Can also check google for legal ways of getting and using Win 10 for free, so you have two well supported OSs.

Comment: It is recommended to back up important files/data first.  Change sda2 to ext4 format from fat32.  Vista is most likely installed with legacy bios, will have to install ubuntu same way.  To change Windows partition/s always use Windows tools/programs for safety.

Comment: I have answered your question. Also, why aren't you using Install alongside Windows option? If you can't see that, you will run into issues in the future. Also, it is a good practice to reply to comments and use @username when replying.

Comment: The recommended minimum is 25gb, so keep your software/files to a minimum, maintain it very closely and you'll likely need to nuke & re-install come upgrade time if you're talking desktop. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements

Answer (score 0):

**20GB is probably not enough.** If 20GB is not enough, resize the Windows partition again before starting the install.

1. Select the partition you want and press the `-` sign. This will delete that partition and free up space.
2. Create a `/swap` partition. Select free space and press the `+` button and set the parameters as in the image below. To find out how large this should be and to learn more about `swap` read [Swap Faq](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq).

   [image: Swap]
3. Create a `/` (root) partition. Select free space and press the `+` button and set the parameters as in the image below. Have at least 20GB to be on the safe side. (I have 40). For the type of partition, you can chose "primary".

   [image: /root]
4. You don't have space to create a separate `/home` partition. So your personal files will be stored in the `/` (root) partition.
5. Press "Install now".

**However, I too recommend that you upgrade windows somehow and choose Ubuntu 20.04 LTS instead of 16.04.**

After install, you will need to make sure that you create a separate NTFS partition so that you can share files between Windows and Ubuntu through it.

For more information on installing read [How to use manual partitioning during installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation/343352#343352).

Comment: I wouldn't suggest making a separate `/home` on this small space. Also I see no reason of creating logical partitions.

Comment: I got those images from the link above. I'll edit the post.